# integral of $\frac{c}{\sin(x)\sqrt{\sin^2(x)-c^2}}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, substitution

In a script I found that the indefinite integral of $\int{\frac{c}{\sin(x)\sqrt{\sin^2(x)-c^2}}dx}$ is $\sin^{-1}(\frac{\cot(x)}{c})$. I know that $\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} = \cot^2(x)+1$. I wanted to use this to substitute $y=\frac{\cot(x)}{c}$ and hoped to then get something of the form $\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}dy}$ but it did not work. Am I completely on the wrong track or did I miss something? 
Thank you!

Comment: If I differentiate $\arcsin(c^{-1}\cot x)$ I don't get the integrand.

Comment: According to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+c%2F%7Bsin%28x%29*sqrt%5B%28sin%28x%29%29%5E2-c%5E2%5D%7D+dx) $\arcsin{\left(\frac{\cot(x)}{c}\right)}$ is not the primitive you are looking for.

Comment: If it helps, I get the primitive $$-\arctan\Bigl(\frac{c\cos x}{\sqrt{\sin^2x-c^2}}\Bigr).$$(There was exactly the same integrand in a question yesterday, and it is a good idea to put $u=\cos x$ or even $u=\cos x/\sqrt{\sin^2x-c^2}$).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I got it: First, rewrite the integrand as $$\dfrac1{\sin x\sqrt{\sin^2x-c^2}}=\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin^2x\sqrt{\sin^2x-c^2}}=\dfrac{-\cos'x}{(1-\cos^2x)\sqrt{1-\cos^2x-c^2}}~,$$ then, after doing the obvious trigonometric substitution $t=\cos x,~$ let $a^2=1-c^2,~$ and

$t=au.~$ Then another obvious trigonometric substitution, followed by [Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) and

some [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), then you're done ! :-$)$